# How to disable Configurations History Delivery for account in AWS Config

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

I have configured AWS Config for some of the accounts to notify if there is any public access enabled for the existing or new s3 bucket created, but after enabling aws config I am receiving notification daily, regarding the Configurations History Delivery for account XXXXXXXXXX. How to disable the history delivery I want to reduce the noise to the mail box. Only want to notify if there are any configurations changes related to s3 public access. I can't find any specific option in aws config to disable this.